# Load JQuery where it's needed in AngularJS project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an animated 404 Error page created using JQuery.

The only to make it work with my AngularJS project is if i had the jquery.min.js, 404.js, 404.min.css and a javascript script tag in the index.html however, this creates unnecessary loading on my other pages and slows down the website.

I found this https://github.com/manuelmazzuola/angular-ui-router-styles but it looks like it's designed only for CSS stylesheets or can i use to include JS files too?

How should I load this JS, CSS files only on my partials, 404.html file and not on index.html?

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for lazy loading.

Normally, all the JavaScript that pertains to a certain web page or application is loaded immediately during page load.

**Lazy loading** is loading code only once the user needs it. So if you have a button on your page that will show a completely different screen to the user once it is pressed,

[Require Js](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) Serve this purpose well and clean.

Take a look at below code from my project

```
 $('#somebutton').on('click', function() {
    require(
        ['every', 'javascript', 'dependency', 'for', 'other', 'screen'], 
        function(ev, js, dep, fr, othr, scrn){
            // Create the screen with your dependencies
        }
    );
});
```